# Is there notifications for Facebook Real-time Updates?

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

When using Real-time updates :

- The User object supports Real-Time Updates for the following connection : friends

Question : is there a notification when a friend updates their profile (name, address, phone, picture ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no notification in [Facebook Real-time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) for friends details, only changes to `friends` connection of [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) object are triggering notification (addition/removal of friends), and you will not get the details of change, just the fact that list of friends have changed...